# How to create Firefox search plugin for GAE docs?

Tags: search, firefox-addon

The main problem here is with search url:

> http://code.google.com/intl/it/query/#p=appengine&q=query

It doesn't contain `?` symbol, also it has `#` symbol.
Such URL doesn't pass XML validation, so I've tried different other approaches (even inclusion of additional parameter), but haven't found working solution.

Here is what I have currently (image part is truncated for simplification):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"  
                       xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">  
  <ShortName>Google AppEngine</ShortName>  
  <Description>Search the GAE documents at Google Code website.</Description>  
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>  
  <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">data:image/x-icon;base64,...</Image>  
  <Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://code.google.com/intl/it/query/#p=appengine">  
    <Param name="a" value="{moz:locale}"/>
    <Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>  
  </Url>  
  <moz:SearchForm>http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/</moz:SearchForm>  
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use entity `&amp;` to encode the `&`, and the XML will be valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"  
                       xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">  
  <ShortName>Google AppEngine</ShortName>  
  <Description>Search the GAE documents at Google Code website.</Description>  
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>  
  <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">data:image/x-icon;base64,25</Image>  
  <Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://code.google.com/intl/it/query/#p=appengine&amp;q={searchTerms}"></Url>  
  <moz:SearchForm>http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/</moz:SearchForm>  
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Copy this XML to http://validator.w3.org/check to confirm the validilty.